# iPhone Simulator Translucent Black Screen and Hangs in Xcode 4.4.1

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5, xcode4.4

I have a problem with Xcode 4.4.1 .

My Simulator becomes translucent black and hangs without any proper log message when I pressed a login button of my application after app launch.

Sometimes application or Simulator hangs just after the launch when I pressed the button or Sometimes it hangs after few second I request a network call with in application.

No pattern .. no message to trace. Tried many things like Xcode restart ,System restart and Clear logs and deleting temporary iPhone Simulator files in Library like that .

I am not able to get what is happening . Does anyone suggest me solution to get out of this.
Or Does somebody know the reason why this is happening. I mean its the application problem i.e in code or the Xcode or iPhone Simulator App problem.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Could be any number of things. Can you build some Apple sample code for iPhone and run it on the simulator?  Also, what happens when you update your Xcode 4.4.1 to the current version which is 4.5?  Also, if you set a breakpoint in the first few lines of your app (e.g. "`applicationDidFinishLaunching:`"), does it hit?

Comment: Actually my project was initially running on Xcode 3 and now I have upgraded it and also convert it for ARC but both the codes having ARC and non-ARC are giving hang state in this new Xcode 4.4.1.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem last day. I got it working after I have done the following, not sure which step did the trick.

- Reset the simulator contents.
- Quit simulator
- Delete derived data of    the project from xcode.
- Restart xcode.

Comment: Yes I tried all these things ,it just restart it from initial state that means Simulator runs the application just for once after performing these tasks but again back to same hang state with translucent black screen...